# Clean up the code for LeetCode Evaluate Reverse Polish Notation

Tags: c++

I have written the following code for LeetCode OJ problem [Evaluate Reverse Polish Notation](https://leetcode.com/problems/evaluate-reverse-polish-notation/)

```
int evalRPN(vector<string>& tokens) 
{
    int n = tokens.size();
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    stack<int> S;
    int a, b;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        string tmp = tokens[i];
        if (tmp == "+")
        {
            a = S.top(); S.pop();
            b = S.top(); S.pop();
            S.push(b + a);
        }
        else if (tmp == "-")
        {
            a = S.top(); S.pop();
            b = S.top(); S.pop();
            S.push(b - a);
        }
        else if (tmp == "*")
        {
            a = S.top(); S.pop();
            b = S.top(); S.pop();
            S.push(b * a);
        }
        else if (tmp == "/")
        {
            a = S.top(); S.pop();
            b = S.top(); S.pop();
            S.push(b / a);
        }
        else
        {
            S.push(stoi(tmp));
        }
    }
    return S.top();
}
```

The code is undoubtedly correct. However, some part of the code I feel is not clean. Actually, I would like to write the code like this:

```
int evalRPN(vector<string>& tokens) 
{
    int n = tokens.size();
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    stack<int> S;
    int a, b;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        string tmp = tokens[i];
        if (tmp is any of "+", "-", "*", "/") // <== [1]
        {
            a = S.top(); S.pop();
            b = S.top(); S.pop();
            S.push(compute(a, b, tmp)); // <== [2]
        }
        else
        {
            S.push(stoi(tmp));
        }
    }
    return S.top();
}
```

1. In `[1]`, I don't want to write `tmp == "+" || tmp == "-" || tmp == "*" || tmp == "/"`, I want cleaner code to check `tmp` is any of the four operators;
2. In `[2]`, the function `compute(int a, int b, string& tmp)` will output the result of operands `a`, `b` and operator `tmp`. But still I don't want to use any `if - else` (`switch` may be accepted, but I don't know how to use here for `string`). Lambda functions or any possible operator functions are welcome, if exist.

Is there some ways to do that?

Comment: Some languages like SQL have the keyword `in` which would allow you to do things like you request in 1, however I'm pretty sure there isn't anything similar in C++.

Comment: i hate writing lots of condition statements

Comment: Could pass an array to a method then loop through the array.

Comment: no love for the switch statement?

Comment: yes. just show me the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work with C++11 or greater. (if using g++ compile with `-std=c++11` flag).

```
#include <map>
#include <functional>
// ...

int evalRPN(vector<string>& tokens) 
{
    // map of string -> lambda
    std::map<std::string, std::function<int(int,int)>> ops;

    // fill the map 
    ops["+"] = [](int a,int b) { return b+a; };
    ops["-"] = [](int a,int b) { return b-a; };
    ops["*"] = [](int a,int b) { return b*a; };
    ops["/"] = [](int a,int b) { return b/a; };    

    int n = tokens.size();
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;

    stack<int> S;
    int a, b;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        string tmp = tokens[i];
        // find the operator in map
        auto opit = ops.find(tmp);
        if ( opit != ops.end() ) {
            // if token is in map (ie. if it is operator)
            a = S.top(); S.pop();
            b = S.top(); S.pop();
            // get the function
            auto fn = opit->second;
            // and push it's result to stack
            S.push( fn(a,b) );
        } else {
            // if not operator push to stack
            S.push(stoi(tmp));
        }

    }
    return S.top();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At least, I can give you a solution for the first part of your problem, i.e. the if-statement. I think the following could work:

```
std::string operators = "+-*/";
std::string tmp = tokens[i];
if(operators.find(tmp) != std::string::npos)
{
    a = S.top(); S.pop();
    b = S.top(); S.pop();
    S.push(compute(a, b, tmp)); // <== [2]
}
else
{
    S.push(stoi(tmp));
}
```

What I do here is simple: I have a string that contains all operators and I just search for `tmp` inside that string. If its position inside that string is not `npos`, tmp has to be an operator.

For the second part, I have 2 ideas:

It's still a bit clumsy, but you wrote a `switch` statement would be acceptable, so how about this:

```
int compute(int a, int b, std::string op)
{
    switch (op[0]) {
        case '+':
            return b+a;
        case '-':
            return b-a;
        case '*':
            return b*a;
        case '/':
            return b/a;
    }
}
```

The other idea: Initially, I thought you could use `operator+` and co to avoid writing your won functions for something that's already implemented, but as it turns out that's impossible. However there are other functions that you can use:

```
int compute(int a, int b, std::string op)
{
    static std::map<std::string,std::function<int(int,int)> >  operations;
    operations["+"] = std::plus<int>();
    operations["-"] = std::minus<int>();
    operations["*"] = std::multiplies<int>();
    operations["/"] = std::divides<int>();

    return operations[op](b,a);
}
```

Take a look at http://ideone.com/wSl5zQ for a full implementation that reads one line of RPN form stdin and calculates the result.

Comment: it should be `b-a` and `b/a`

Comment: @stjepano Thanks, I changed it. Your solution is nicer anyway. By the way: Did you also try replacing the lambdas with the builtin operator-functions? I can't get that to work because they're overloaded.

Comment: No I did not try that but it sounds like it should work.